# Need to close all popup which is open on stage . Action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

i have created one flash example.. in which there are 4 tabs.. i am opening 4 movieclips.
here is my code.

```
for (var i:int = 1; i <numOfbutton; i++) {
                mc = getChildByName("tab"+i) as MovieClip;
                this["tab" + i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fun);
                this["tab" + i].id = i;
                this["tab" + i].buttonMode  = true;
                mcArray.push(mc);
            }


var j:Number=mc2.id;
var mc1:MovieClip=this.getChildByName("pop"+e.target.id) as MovieClip;
mc1.gotoAndPlay(2);
```

so i have to close all the popups on Menu button.

```
btnMenu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , showMainScreen)


public function showMainScreen() {
                //code
        }
```

So can anybdy suggest me....what should i write //code

Answer (score 0):

If you know the names of your popups, you can try to use something like this:

```
    stage.removeChild(stage.getChildByName("yourPopUpId"));
```